# Limit of regular polygons approaching pi - earliest proofs

Tags: approximation, pi

Archimedes used areas of regular polygons to approximate pi. He calculated both inner and outer polygons and realized that more sides yielded closer results to each other. There's surviving proof that he did this through at least the 96 side polygon.

Did Archimedes or any other ancient actually prove that the inner and outer techniques would converge? It's pretty easy to show that the ratio of an inner to outer line segment approximation is the cosine of half 
the angle of one side of the polygon, and that the ratio of an area approximation would be cosine squared. As such as the number of sides increase, the two techniques converge.

Did anybody from the distant past mention an argument similar to this and drive that point home? Or did they merely realize that each subsequent iteration of inner and outer was getting closer to each other?

Comment: It's called the [method of exhaustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_exhaustion).  It's not a formal proof in the sense that we would have today, but it did show that the remaining extra/missing area decreased like a geometric series.

Comment: I think the method of exhaustion says you can always get closer to the real value. But does it actually say you can get arbitrarily close?

Comment: I'm not sure the difference between 'closer' and 'arbitrarily close' was usually clearly understood until calculus-like concepts became mainstream.

Comment: Archimedes didn't show that exhaustion would converge. Anyway, it is quite easy to show that it converges, since at every step the "error" gets smaller than half of the previous step's "error".

Comment: Thanks Crostul - that "error" being half of the prior step is even more obvious than the cosine squared argument.

Answer (score 0):

Archimedes proved (up to a significant rewording) that for the unit circle, for any value less than $\pi$, he could find an inscribed polygon whose area was greater than that value, and that for any value greater than $\pi$, he could find a circumscribed polygon whose area was less than $\pi$.

With the exception of showing that the perimeter of the circumscribed polygon must be greater than the circumference of the circle, his proof is quite rigorous. (The exception only occurs because Archimedes did not have a rigorous definition of arclengh, and so could not prove this one part rigorously.)

In modern parlance, it amounts to a proof that there are two sequences of polygons whose areas converge to $\pi$. One from below, and the other from above. His estimation for $\pi$ comes from polygons that can be shown to be on those sequences.